# make a NSGradient from a given NSColor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gradient, nscolor

I have a function that paints a particular area with the `NSColor` that is passed to it. To give it a sort of 3D look I need to paint it with a gradient of the given color. Suppose `NSColor` is `blueColor` then the area should be painted with something like `lightBlue` to `blueColor` or something as such so that I can get a slight gradient effect.

So my question is how can I create `NSColor` which is lighter than the `NSColor` that is passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [NSColor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) "Changing the Color" section. There are several methods to make a new color form existing one:

```
– blendedColorWithFraction:ofColor:
– colorWithAlphaComponent:
– highlightWithLevel:
– shadowWithLevel:
```

Also you can create a new color with RGB components calculated from your existing color (or HSB components) with

```
+ colorWithCalibratedHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:
+ colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha:
```

Comment: Adding you'll want to try lowering the brightness of a color a bit by creating a new color with less bright (0.9?) than the original.